# How do I play this Audio Frame struct? - Microsoft mixed-reality webrtc

Tags: c#, winforms, audio-streaming

The title is pretty self explanatory.

I'm using Microsoft's webrtc API and each `AudioFrame` object has the following fields:

```
public IntPtr audioData;
           
public uint bitsPerSample;
        
public uint sampleRate;
        
public uint channelCount;        
       
public uint sampleCount;
```

How would I go about playing this (if possible using no external libraries)?

I'm targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2 in a Winforms application.

TIA